# Create a link to a named destination in a PDF file with PymuPDF

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

I wanted to create a link that is associated with a named destination of a PDF file using PymuPDF, The program runs, but it doesn't create t any link.

```
# Import the PyMuPDF library
import fitz
# Open the source PDF file
doc = fitz.open("pdf-with-named-destination.pdf")
from_rect=fitz.Rect(50, 50, 100,100)

# Get the fourth page of the source PDF file
page = doc\[3\]
# Define the named link
namedlink={"kind": fitz.LINK_NAMED
    , "name": "nameddest=anchor4"
    , "from": from_rect  
}


# Insert the link to the page`your text`
page.insert_link(namedlink)
idx=0

# Print links

for page in doc:
    idx = idx + 1
    links=page.get_links()
    if len(links) \> 0:
        print("------ Page No.: " + str(idx)+"------:")

        for link in links:
        print(link)
        print("\n")

# Save the modified source PDF file
doc.save("pdf-with-named-destination-link.pdf")
doc.close()
doc=None
```

Comment: I am maintainer of PyMuPDF: there is a bug in the skeleton for named destinations. Fix developed, should be rolled out with the next version.  As [KJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10802527/k-j) mentioned: the whole thing works in "rebased" architecture (fitz_new) only.

Comment: KJ,   I added a few of named destinations to the PDF file with Adobe Acrobat Pro before I ran the program above.  So I am sure there are named destinations in the input PDF file.  I ran the program, no errors were reported, but no links were created either.

Comment: KJ,  I  replaced  "Import  fitz" with "import fitz_new as fitz".  This time, the program produced the error as follows:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\python\proj-rtf-to-pdf\create-named-link.py:37
    links=page.get_links()

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\fitz_new\utils.py:1023 in get_links
    nl = getLinkDict(ln, page.parent)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\fitz_new\utils.py:1005 in getLinkDict
    nl['to'] = fitz.Point(nl['to'])

KeyError: 'to'